# Is their any way to Loop through data of array & create another array from it?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a array from this input:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 85
        [time] => 2020-07-18 13:34:59
        [user] => 32
        [status] => read
        [type] => profile_view
        [content] => One has viewed your profile. 
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 79
        [time] => 2020-07-20 12:16:03
        [user] => 32
        [status] => read
        [type] => profile_view
        [content] => test buyer has viewed your profile.
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 76
        [time] => 2020-07-20 12:59:11
        [user] => 32
        [status] => read
        [type] => profile_view_guest
        [url] => 
        [content] => A guest has viewed your profile.
    )
)
```

to output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [label] => July 18 2020
        [y] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [label] => July 20 2020
        [y] => 1
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [label] => July 20 2020
        [y] => 1
    )
)
```

Here `[y]` will number of times the date repeats here from the input.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This isn’t a place to ask basic “how to” questions all the time. You are supposed to show what you tried first of all.

Comment: Also, please format the code you have shown, and introduce some line breaks, so that we don’t have to scroll sideways for five miles to see what your data actually is.

Comment: Please explain what does `[y] => 0` mean how you think to get that?

Comment: Here [y] will number of times the date repeat here from input.

Comment: Not sure how to do it.

Comment: Your output example is incorrect. [y] does not reflect your question.

Comment: Your answer works, thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the below example

```php
<?php

// This is your input array
$input = [ ... ];

$output = [];

foreach ( $input as $data ) {
    
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $data->time );
    $formatted = $date->format( 'F j Y' );

    // Create empty count
    if ( !array_key_exists( $formatted, $output ) ) {
        $output[ $formatted ] = [
            'label' => $formatted,
            'y' => 0
        ];
    }

    // Increase count
    $output[ $formatted ][ 'y' ]++;

}

// Remove keys
$output = array_values( $output );

print_r( $output );
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => July 18 2020
            [y] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => July 20 2020
            [y] => 2
        )

)
```

Test here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6b7be9876828c41235e01b1e7eb6434f65db5f1